# Add attributes to List<bool> objects or similar so I can iterate through them

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a class something like this

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class someClass
{
    public someClass()
    {
        someVarA = true;
        someVarB = true;
        someVarC = true;
    }

    [DataMember]
    [DisplayName(@"Some cool var displayname")]
    public bool someVarA {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    [DisplayName(@"Some other cool name")]
    public bool someVarB {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    [DisplayName(@"Boring")]
    public bool someVarC {get;set;}
}
```

The problem is it requires a lot of coding to set or read these values, just look at the constructor for example, I have one class with 20 values in it in the "real" code!

I would really like them to become a list somehow, but I am uncertain how to do this while maintaining their 2 attributes (`DataContract` and `DisplayName`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a your own class/struct to combine bool and string? Something along the lines of:

```
public class MyThing
{
    bool myBool;
    string myName;
}
```

And then you can do:

```
var myList = new List<MyThing>();

myList.Add(new MyThing() { myBool = true , myName="Displayname" });
```

Comment: Have thought of that, but where would you plaster on the attributes?